Swift: How wait for all my completion handlers to complete before updating published variable
Im currently using the GooglePlaces API to search for nearby restaurants. GooglePlacesAPI is weird such that the return value of the search gives a GMSPlace object that has a .photos property that only gives metaData. As a result, theres a separate api call where I have to loop through each of those metadata objects and call getPhotoFromMetaData.
See documentation here 
This is the code I have so far. The cardModels is a view model that's being watch my UI and updates the cardstack. Can someone provide a more efficient and correct way to do this? The append behavior is making my UI actually append a card to the top of the stack visually every time. My intended behavior is that I want all the api calls to completely finish. Then use all of the info I got form them and make 1 single update to the cardModels variable. I assume that would remove this weird visual stacking of each card loading.
import Foundation
import GooglePlaces

class CardsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cardModels = [CardModel]()
    
    init() {
        var models = [CardModel]()
        GooglePlacesAPI().performNearbyRestaurantSearch { gmsplaces in
            gmsplaces.forEach { place in
                GooglePlacesAPI().getPhotoFromMetaData(id: place.placeID!) { image in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.cardModels.append(CardModel(restaurant: RestaurantModel(
                            id: place.placeID,
                            name: place.name,
                            uiimages: [image]
                        )))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I tried using DispatchGroup and it seemed to work. Can anyone comment on the validity of using Dispatch group and if that's the most efficient way? Or is there a better way to do this?

Dispatch group is designed for precisely for this purpose, so that’s fine. That having been said, nowadays we’d use Swift concurrency and a task group. But that’s beyond the scope of this question.

By the way, we obviously cannot comment on your dispatch group attempt without seeing it. For example, if you’re using the dispatch group notify, that’s fine. But if you’re using its wait method, then that generally would not be considered a good idea. We cannot comment on code you haven’t shared with us.

Switch to async/await
